# DevOps Services tests not working in BlueMix/hub.jazz with Go

Tags: go, ibm-cloud, devops

I'm trying to run tests on my software as it's about to be deployed via git to blueMix. Currently the pipeline is 'build stage' -> 'deploy stage', and now I'm trying to implement the 'test stage' in the middle of that process.

My test stage has a test job, and the `Tester Type` is `simple`. The command I have currently is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# invoke tests here
go test
```

, however the test stage fails and returns:

```
_build.sh: line 3: go: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Evidently go isn't installed at the testing stage. Do I get the test server to install Go on each new git push to test it, or am I sorely mistaken?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like $GOROOT is not set for that bash session. Add `echo $GOROOT` before your `go test` to see if it is.

Comment: It returns nothing for both $GOPATH and $GOROOT. When I try execute `/usr/bin/go`, the following is returned: `_build.sh: line 6: /usr/bin/go: No such file or directory`

Comment: do you have go installed in `/usr/bin/go`?

Comment: So far the 'test commands' install Go, set the environment variables and I'm currently stuck at getting godep working such that `go test` may run the tests. Is this the correct approach towards getting the tests to run?

Comment: @Patrick Have you managed to make this work? In particular, how did you install Go?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct.  There are only certain tools pre-installed in the enviroment that runs the jobs.  You can find them here: https://hub.jazz.net/docs/deploy_var/#resources - Everything else would have to be installed each time the job is run.